# How do I test run the restricted app in facebook?

Tags: facebook

Recently One of facebook app has been restricted by facebook saying the app is redirecting off of facebook. Now I want to test run the app in facebook. According to this website https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps I need to click on test apps but I dont find any Test apps link in app's page. Please help

Comment: What do you mean by “in app's page”? This is in the app _dashboard_, where you configure all the app settings. App pages are something different.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your comment .  It's not in the dashboard I checked it

Comment: Looks like the interface has changed a bit. Click on the dropdown arrow next to the app name in the upper left corner - in the popout there’s a button “Create Test App”.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you I will check it.